# Mongo DB pull data to php table

Tags: php, apache, mongodb

Hi guys so im switching over from MySQL to MongoDB as my server runs far more efficient on it. I need to update one of my pages i have figured out most of the code and im not getting any database errors I believe im just not putting the data in the correct order. As when the page loads there is no content.

Here is my database info there will be multiple arrays like the one below in the Database TEST. I would like it to pull all of the ones with the PENDING NameState into the table.

```
 array(
"_id"=>100000005,
"dclass"=>"Distributed",
"fields"=>array(
    "Name"=>array(
        "_0"=>"Testing",
    ),
    "NameState"=>array(
        "_0"=>"PENDING",
    ),
     'setName': {
        '_0': 'test name'
```

Here is my database query 
$m is defined with my database connection

```
$search = $m->fields->(array('NameState'=>'PENDING'));
```

Then here is my table where i want the id to show, the current setname And the name.

```
foreach ($SEARCH as $row) {
                echo "<tr>";
                $ID = $row['_id'];
                echo "<td>" . $row['_id'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['SetName'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
                $NAME = $row['Name'] . "</td";
                echo "</tr>";
```

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the exact format of your data then the problem is, it is not a JSON format. Your content must be in JSON format rather than any arbitrary string.
I have added two documents in collection named 'testData'

```
> db.testData.find()
{ "_id" : 100000005, "dclass" : "Distributed", "fields" : { "Name" : "Testing", "NameState" : "PENDING" } }
{ "_id" : 100000006, "dclass" : "Distributed", "fields" : { "Name" : "Testing Excluded", "NameState" : "NOT PENDING" } }
```

In php my query is like this,

```
$m = new \MongoClient();
$collection = $m->selectCollection('mydb', 'testData');
$list = $collection->find();

$query = array('fields.NameState' => 'PENDING');

$cursor = $collection->find($query);
foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
    var_dump($doc);
}
```

Result is :

```
array(3) { ["_id"]=> float(100000005) ["dclass"]=> string(11) "Distributed" ["fields"]=> array(2) { ["Name"]=> string(7) "Testing" ["NameState"]=> string(7) "PENDING" } }
```

Comment: If you can provide me an example I should be decent enough to research the rest on my own. Thanks Ryan